# Separate a sentence into words and endmarks

Tags: regex, r

I want to break a sentence apart into words and end marks (assume all other punctuation has been removed).  I've written a working function to break string(s) apart as described but I think the part:

```
unlist(c(strsplit(x, "[^[:alnum:]'\"]", perl = T), substring(x, nchar(x), nchar(x))))
```

is a cob job that can be better achieved without using the substring and just splitting on spaces and between the endmark with an or | statement of sorts but don't know how I'd achieve this.  Any direction with this would be appreciated.

```
breaker <- function(string) {
    FUN <- function(x) {
        unlist(c(strsplit(x, "[^[:alnum:]'\"]", perl = T), substring(x, 
            nchar(x), nchar(x))))
    }
    lapply(string, FUN)
} 

#EXAMPLES

x <- "I'm liking it!"                                                          
breaker(x)                                                                     

y <- c("I'm liking it!", "How much do you like it?",  "I'd say it's awesome.") 
breaker(y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex pattern that'll do the whole job on its own.  It will match (and thus allow `strsplit()` to split the string) *either* at a space *or* right before one of the sentence-ending punctuation marks.

```
pat <- "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?])"
```

The first half of the pattern matches space characters, and any match will cause `strsplit()` to 'eat up' the matched characters when it splits the string. The second half of the pattern (the part inside of the `(?=...)`) matches sentence-ending punctuation. It is an example of a 'zero-width positive lookahead assertion' (see [`?regexp`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) for details), and as such, will **not** lead `strsplit()` to 'eat up' the matching punctuation.

For your example vectors, you don't even need the call to `lapply()`:

```
breaker <- function(X) {
    strsplit(X, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?])", perl=TRUE)
}

x <- "I'm liking it!"                                                          
breaker(x)                                                                     

y <- c("I'm liking it!", "How much do you like it?",  "I'd say it's awesome.") 
breaker(y)
```

Comment: Much more eloquent.  Thank you Josh.  This also adds to my understanding of regex.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use scan_tokenizer() and MC_tokenizer() from the tm package

```
> library(tm)
> ?MC_tokenizer
> MC_tokenizer("what are the number of words in this sentence?")
[1] "what"     "are"      "the"      "number"   "of"       "words"    "in"      
[8] "this"     "sentence"
```

Comment: these functions appear to break the sentence apart into words but either strip the punctuation or attach it to the final word of the sentence.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I did not notice "end marks" part earlier.